# zf2 - Retrieve the 'ApplicationConfig' in a 'ActionController'

Tags: zend-framework2

I realise that there shouldn't be to many reasons for us to access the `ApplicationConfig` from a controller. But I'm still asking.. Is there a way to do that?

What I actually wishes to do is to get a hold of the
`module_listener_options` -> `config_glob_paths` key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @timdev didn't get your point, your question could be solved by:

```
$applicationConfig = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ApplicationConfig');
```

Comment: Strange, I thought I tryed that. But now it Works. I guss I must have misspelt or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// in a controller (or anything that is ServiceLocatorAware)
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
```

Will give you an array of your application's merged configuration data.